# Return substring where multiple instances exist in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to search a MySQL forum database for all instances of a certain string

This string may be contained several times in one post, and this should return a match for each instance.

```
ID  PostContent
1   This is a post with a http://example.com/whatever
    link and it links once
2   This is a link to http://example.com/this1 but also
    look at http://example.com/this2
3   This post has no links
4   This has one link to http://example.com/link
```

I would like this to return

```
1  http://example.com/whatever
2  http://example.com/this1
3  http://example.com/this2
4  http://example.com/link
```

Can anyone suggest how this could be achieved. I could use the regex to return posts that contain 'http://example.com/', however I am struggling with how to handle returns with multiple instances.

Thanks

Comment: SQL can't easily return multiple rows from one row in the table. This is better done in the client application language.

Comment: @Barmar: Just what I was thinking.